# kurento-tutorial-node - Error message from server: Could not find media server at addressws://localhost:8888/kurento

Tags: kurento

I have just installed Kurento Media Server and I'm reviewing its Node tutorials.
Some of them work flawlessly.
However I have identical issue to the another ones e.g. `kurento-platedetector` - when it is loaded into the page and the **Start** button is pressed, in the **Remote Stream** I see nothing but progress circle and in the console I can see the following error reported:

```
Error message from server: Could not find media server at addressws://localhost:8888/kurento. Exiting with error SyntaxError: Module 'platedetector' is not installed in the Kurento Media Server
```

Note: One important clarification regarding the environment - I have installed the Kurento Media Server on a separate machine reachable within the local network, hence the way I call it from client machine is 192.168.x.x:8443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tutorials need extra modules to be installed in the media server. You need to install the `kms-platedetector` debian package with

```
sudo apt-get install kms-platedetector-6.0
```

and restart your KMS afterwards.

If your KMS is located in a different machine than the one you are running the tutorial, you'll need to tell that to the KurentoClient by starting the Node.js server app with a flag

```
npm start -- --ws_uri=ws://kms_host:kms_host:kms_port/kurento
```

That's in the documentation, and can be found [here](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-helloworld.html#for-the-impatient-running-this-example).

Comment: Thanks, for the hints, however few clarifications are required: 
1) Adding additional pakcages is not pointed out in the documentation or at least in Node Tutorials.
2) the exact package name is `kms-platedetector-6.0`. 
3) Once #2 is done you don't need to start NodeJS server as by your proposal above (`ws_uri` parameter), since NodeJS server and KMS are on the same machine, hence simple `npm start` do the work. 
Anyways - thanks now I can run the NodeJS samples.

Comment: @AngelTodorov We'll try to add that to the documentation, but the error message in the server should give you a hint. As to needing or not the ws_uri, the answer already states that you only need doing that if your kms and node app are located in different machines. I've edited the post to have the correct package name, thanks!